# Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell_id - must register a nib or a class for the identifier

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I writing xamarin.ios app and using TableView.

I want to Create a custom cell.

So in the designer, I created it with this properties

[image]

I try to use it then in TableSource

Like this

```
 public class ExperienceSource : UITableViewSource
{
    Experience[] TableItems;
    //NSString cellIdentifier = new NSString("TableCell");
    ExperienceController owner;
    public ExperienceSource(Experience[] items, ExperienceController owner)
    {
        TableItems = items;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return TableItems.Length;
    }




    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("cell_id", indexPath) as ExperienceCell;
        //Experience item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];
        /*if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new ExperienceCell(cellIdentifier);
        }*/
        cell.UpdateCell(TableItems[indexPath.Row].title, TableItems[indexPath.Row].price);
        //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        /*if (cell == null)
        { 
            cell = new ()(CellIdentifier); 
        }*/
        return cell;
    }
}
```

And Here is class for ExperienceCell

```
 public partial class ExperienceCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public ExperienceCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
    internal void UpdateCell(string title, string price)
    {
        ExperienceTitle.Text = title;
        ExperincePrice.Text = price;
    }
}
```

When I run app, I got this error

> unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell_id - must register a nib
>   or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a
>   storyboard

How I can fix this?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Is your cell created within the TableView in the iOS designer? Or is it defined in a separate file?

Comment: Separate file . @nmilcoff

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the registration of the UITableViewCell in the UITableView.

Please add something like this in your ViewController (the important part is the `RegisterNibForCellReuse` sentence):

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    MyTableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(UINib.FromName(nameof(ExperienceCell), NSBundle.MainBundle), "cell_id");

    MyTableView.Source = new ExperienceSource(..., ...);    

    // .. your code
}
```

This is a necessary step when you declare your UITableViewCells outside the UITableView.